# How to emit data to kotlin flow

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

How can I emit new data to an existing Kotlin `Flow`? Currently I can only do it inside the `flow` block like this:

```
val data: Flow<Boolean> = flow {
    emit(newData)
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
fun someMethod() {
    data.emit(newData)
}
```

I can do it if I use Android `LiveData`:

```
val data: LiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

fun someMethod() {
    data.postValue(newData) // data.value = newData
}
```

or something likes it in RxJava2 with `onNext` event

**Update**: `flow` is not designed to do it. So I will check another approach

Comment: [1](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1140) [2](https://medium.com/@elizarov/kotlin-flows-and-coroutines-256260fb3bdb)

Comment: This type of multicast is not directly supported by their standard library. You can try some [3rd party library](https://github.com/akarnokd/kotlin-flow-extensions#publishsubject) though.